# Javascript: Como inserir vários espaços em branco em um elemento parágrafo <p>?

Tags: javascript, html5

Boa tarde!

Estou inserindo dentro de uma **TAG HTML `<p>`** alguns espaços em branco, para completar o número de caracteres dentro uma certa descrição (120).

Preciso que os espaços em branco fiquem **visíveis** na página.

Abaixo a **TAG**:

**`<p class="descricao">Exemplo de texto</p>`**

Porém estou tendo um problema ao adicionar os espaços em branco. 
Tentei utilizar o carácter **ALT + 255**, vulgo **''**, mas os espaços não estão sendo inseridos, tentei também fazer uso de **'`&nbsp;`'** mas não funcionou.

Fiz alguns testes, e quando substituo o carácter branco por letras e números, funciona normalmente.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Segue abaixo o código **Javascript** que estou utilizando:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="descricao">Exemplo de texto</p>

<script>

var publicacoes = $( '.descricao' );

   for (var i = 0; i < publicacoes.length; i++)
   {
   var texto = publicacoes[i].textContent;
   var textoComplementar = "&nbsp;";

   for (var j = 0; j < (120 - texto.length); j++)
   {
        texto += textoComplementar;
   }

   publicacoes[i].textContent = texto;
   }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar `innerHTML` para conseguir reconhecer os `&nbsp;` porém também vai ter que aumentar o tamanho no `for`, porque `&nbsp;` não tem um caractere, tem 6...

Apenas reconhecendo os espaços com innerHTML, porém serão inseridos apenas 15 espaços:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="descricao">Exemplo de texto</p>

<script>

    var publicacoes = $('.descricao');
    var textoComplementar = "&nbsp;";

    for (var i = 0; i < publicacoes.length; i++) {
        
        for (var j = 0; j < (120 - publicacoes[i].innerHTML.length); j++) {
            publicacoes[i].innerHTML = publicacoes[i].innerHTML + textoComplementar;
        }

    }

</script>
```

Agora deixando o texto com 120 caracteres (apenas uma mudança no local da conta)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p class="descricao">Exemplo de texto</p>

<script>

    var publicacoes = $('.descricao');
    var textoComplementar = "&nbsp;";

    for (var i = 0; i < publicacoes.length; i++) {
        var restante = 120 - publicacoes[i].innerHTML.length;

        for (var j = 0; j < restante; j++) {
            publicacoes[i].innerHTML = publicacoes[i].innerHTML + textoComplementar;
        }

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função **padEnd** para adicionar o caracter que desejar quando o tamanho definido não for preenchido. Aqui estamos definindo que o texto da nossa tag vai ser ele mesmo mais o caractere ' ' quando o tamanho de 120 não for atendido.

```
$('#teste').text($('#teste').text().padEnd(120, ' '));
```

Não se esqueça de alterar o **#teste** para o id da sua tag html.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Pedro, o problema é que eu preciso que os espaços em branco possam ser visualizados no HTML, por isso é que estava falando sobre os carácteres especiais.